# python scrapy get value using span=id

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get the word "Profession" from this html line:

```
    <span id="PractitionerDetails1_Label4">Profession:</span>
```

I've tried doing this:

```
sel.css(span[id=PractitionerDetails1_Label4]).extract()
```

It clearly doesn't work. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use text():

```
sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
```